Azure Auth Company Branding not showing all options
I need to make some changes in azure auth proccess.
I'm following this steps to change de default CSS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/fundamentals/how-to-customize-branding
These are the options that I have when I access the menu "company branding". I should be able to see the tab "layout" and change the CSS, but I can't see it.

These are the options that I should see

I already have the Organizational Branding Administrator permission.
Should I have to do a new configuration to see these options or do I need a different permission?
[Edit]
I have 3 directories. Only in 1 directory the options aren't appearing. After @Sridevi I checked the license of this 2 another directories and noticed they have a different type


I have one demo Azure AD B2C tenant with Microsoft Entra ID Free license as below:

When I tried to access Company Branding menu of this tenant with user having 'Organizational Branding Administrator' role, it displayed few options similar to you:

As mentioned in this MS Doc, adding custom branding requires one of the following licenses:

Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2
Microsoft 365 Business Standard
SharePoint (Plan 1)

I have one more tenant with Microsoft Entra ID P2 license as below:

When I tried to access this tenant's Company Branding page with user having 'Organizational Branding Administrator' role, it displayed all options:

UPDATE:
Note that, you can find all options even with  Microsoft Entra ID Free license if your tenant is normal Microsoft Entra tenant.
If it is Azure AD B2C tenant, make sure to acquire at least one of these licenses: Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, SharePoint (Plan 1) to see all options in "Company Branding" page.

Thanks. I have another project that show the options even with Microsoft Entra ID Free license. The only difference is the tenant type. Could please check the tenant type of your 2 projects?

I put a image. I have 3 directories, in other 2 directories the options appears. I already compared all the configs, the only diference that I noticed now is the type. The other 2 have the same free license

For normal Microsoft Entra tenants, it will show all options even with Microsoft Entra ID Free license. But for Azure AD B2C it won't show all options until you get valid license like Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2, Microsoft 365 Business Standard, SharePoint (Plan 1).
